# why a error? \mathbb allowed only in math mode

Tags: amsfonts

[image]

\usepackage{amsfonts}

Пусть \mathbb {N}

LaTeX Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode

Comment: It's an error because `\mathbb` can only be used in math mode, i.e. write `$\mathbb{N}$`.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Also, it helps us a lot if, instead of adding an image, you simply copy and paste the code into the window. Then just highlight it and press ctrl + k or the code sample button (the one like {}).

Comment: Welcome to site! Please, next time copy  code from editor. Image of code we can not compile ...

Comment: Remember that you can also create a wrapper around existing commands: `\newcommand*{\zzz}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{#1}}}` then use `\zzz{N}`.